# Check array of objects using contains - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm having a trouble to find and check if element inside array is it there or not and here is in details:

I've two arrays, containerEntites returns string :

```
var array : [String] = []
var containerEntites: [Qou]!
```

how is it possible to check if the current array value is in containerEntites, I've tried :

```
if contains(containerEntites,array[indexPath.row]) {

}
```

then Xcode provide some help to correct to :

```
    if contains(containerEntites,array[indexPath.row] as! Qou) {

    }
```

Then i get an error saying :

```
Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NSContiguousString' (0x1004f73e0) to 'ExpS.Qou' (0x1001f3400).
```

Class Qou is right here :

```
@objc(Qou)
class Qou: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String

}
```

Anyone may explain whats going on here ?

Comment: What is Qou, how can you compare Qou with String, do you have some specific property on Qou that you want to compare with array element.

Comment: is a name of class which is NSManagedObject and has only one variable which is @NSManaged var name: String.

Comment: Why is your array of strings instead of Qou objects? One way to do this would be to create your own comparison  method, the other would be to extract your names from qou into QouStrings object...

Comment: It says : Cannot find an overload for contains that accept an argument list of type ([Qou]!,String) ? as you answered @NickCatib Btw, both of the arrays are totally doing something else. one for tableview and containerEntities for saving

Comment: Yeah, I realised it seconds after I pressed answer button - thats why I removed it, sorry.

Comment: @NickCatib check my comment please :)

Comment: Sure - but you can use array of Quos to show data. On the other hand you can iterate thru Quos array and check if the .name attribute matches your string... It is bad solution, and I would rather use one array of Quos and if you need to track indexPaths - then array of these indexPaths.